# FastAPI, что значит "Метод "on_event" в классе "FastAPI" не рекомендуется к использованию"?

Tags: python, fastapi

VSCode. В коде перечеркнуто "on_event".
Код вроде работает

Answer (score 1):

В последних версиях метод `on_event` отмечен как устаревший, вместо него рекомендуется использовать `lifespan` для хэндлеров. [Вот](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/) ссылка на раздел документации, где описывается их использование.

Код будет работать и с ним, однако, в следующих версиях, может быть убран, поэтому IDE предупреждает вас, что его использование нежелательно